# Are these different usages of ~?

Tags: bash, shell

`~` means `$HOME`. For example, I often run `cd ~/programs` on my laptop.

But I just saw a usage of `~` without a following backslash, e.g. `~tim/public/` on a server. Does that mean different than when `~` is followed by a backslash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`~` is always your own home.

`~tim` is the home of user `tim`

Comment: Careful, sometimes a tilde is just a tilde, i.e. it does get mapped to your home folder, depends on a lot of factors.